# How is find's {} substitution pattern vulnerable to injection attack?

Tags: find, security

I'm trying to understand more about this edit that was made to an answer of mine:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/510388/5

How does running `cd "{}"` in the context of a find command introduce vulnerability to injection attacks?

For reference, the change made to cover the vulnerability was:

```
diff --git a/command b/command
index 26488d0..fed4c07 100644
--- a/command
+++ b/command
@@ -1 +1 @@
-find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd {} && echo "Spawning a shell in $PWD..." && sh' \;
+find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && echo "Spawning a shell in $PWD..." && sh' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing and wanting to know more!

Answer (score 1):

The directory name is placed where the curly braces are, and is then subject to the shell; consider a `mkdir '$(reboot)'` where `find` will find it. You then end up with `sh` executing: `cd $(reboot)` -- or whatever other command you would like to imagine. The `cd` command will probably fail, unless the attacker is extraordinarily crafty and echos the name of a valid directory there, but the damage is done, regardless.  For less-drastic testing as root, try something like:

```
$ mkdir '$(touch .evil_file; echo directory-name)'`
```

You'll end up with this output:

```
something
sh: line 0: cd: ./directory-name: No such file or directory
```

... **and**:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  .evil_file  $(touch .evil_file; echo directory-name)
```

Comment: Note that even if the `{}` was quoted inside the script, a directory name with the corresponding quotation mark would have broken out of that. Additionally, any directory whose name contains a `;` would probably also have allowed arbitrary code to be executed by the in-line shell script.